# Read Hex file and append string matlab

Tags: string, matlab, hex, comparison

I am reading H.264 bitstream as Hex file in matlab. I want to insert some string whenever some certain condition met.
 [image: Hex file image]
 Like in the attached image if hex value of 00 00 00 01 occurs anywhere in the file i want to add some string like ABC before 00 00 00 01 in the file. String comparison is easy but how to do a Hex comparison?
Here is my code of reading file as hex file

```
   f = fopen(theFile);
    if f==-1
      return
    end
    c = fread(f);
    theSize=prod(size((c)));
    c=sprintf('%02x\n',c);
    c(3:3:end)='';
    m=floor(length(c)/nChars);
    hex='';
    hex=reshape(c(1:m*nChars),nChars,m)';
    if mod(length(c),nChars)
     hex=strvcat(hex,c(m*nChars+1:end));
    end
```

More specifically i want this c code converted into matlab

```
  QByteArray data, basePattern;
  basePattern.resize(3);
  //start code:
  basePattern[0] = (char) 0x00;
  basePattern[1] = (char) 0x00;
  basePattern[2] = (char) 0x01;

  char end1 = 0x25, end2 = 0x45, end3 = 0x65;
       x = myfile;//read using fopen
 if (x == end1 || x == end2  {
}
```

Comment: Why are you manipulating the data at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hex values are really just integers:

```
x = uint8(hex2dec({'01', '02', '0A', '0B', '25', '45', '65', '00', '01', 'AA'}))

x =

    1
    2
   10
   11
   37
   69
  101
    0
    1
  170
```

And they can be compared directly:

```
x(3) == uint8(hex2dec('0a'))

ans =

     1
```

So putting it all together, you should create a new buffer and search through the bytes for the pattern, if it's found, insert you data, if not found, just append the byte:

```
pat0 = uint8(hex2dec('00'));
pat1 = uint8(hex2dec('00'));
pat2 = uint8(hex2dec('01'));

pos = 1;

data = % the uint8 array read in from the file.

new_data = uint8([]);

while pos < length(data) - 2

    if data(pos+0) == pat0 && data(pos+1) == pat1 && data(pos+2) == pat2
        % insert new data buffer and append pattern
        new_data = [new_data my_data_to_insert pat0 pat1 pat2];
        pos = pos + 3;
    else
        % append
        new_data = [new_data data(pos)];
        pos = pos + 1;
    end
end

% append last 2 bytes

new_data = [new_data data(end-1:end)];
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. What if i want to compare stream of hex values like 00 00 00 01? and if i want to append some string before this value occur i.e second part of my question.

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot really see how this is an answer. You may need to improve this post ...